# How objectmapper converts to my object, did it create new instance

Tags: java

I have MyObject:

```
public class MyObject {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    public MyObject(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    // getter, NOT setter here
}
```

I receive message from kafka, and convert to MyObject:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
....
MyObject myObject = objectMapper.convertValue(kafkaMessage.getData(), MyObject.class);
```

Did ObjectMapper create new instance of MyObject by using constructor of MyObject?

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject("name", 12);
```

If not, how can ObjectMapper set value for final fields? Because MyObject only exist constructor, and have NO setter.

Comment: Put a log statement in your constructor and verify yourself.

Comment: You could debug and put a breakpoint in your constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe.

This really depends on the framework you are using. There are multiple possible strategies a mapper can use:

- call a no argument (default) constructor, and then call setter methods. Or directly access the fields of the class to change them.
- identify a matching constructor and pass in arguments, plus the above.

Which strategy is chosen, as said depends on the framework. And actually it does not matter much to you. The whole point of such frameworks is to (de) serialize information for you without bothering you with details.

For more details, start reading here, in their [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/blob/master/README.md).

( and for completeness: from what I know about JSON parsing, I think *jackson* uses heuristics to identify matching constructors and setter methods. whereas libraries such as *gson* expect a default (no arg) constructor, and then use reflection to scan for fields, and update those directly )